# CMake doesn't compile OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, cmake

AFAIK, CMake is a tool for automated builds, so what I would expect from CMake is to "Make" the whole thing, i.e., when I hit "generate" it will create all the files, and compile them, so I will have all I need.

But instead when I run CMake on OpenCV it makes a VS2010 Solution and lots of projects, and then I have to open it in VS2010, and compile the projects myself...why CMake doesn't do it all in a single operation? I think it's capable of doing so right? So why not?

EDIT:

In [this link](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) they show how this is the regular way.

Comment: I'm not on a Windows machine so cannot try this myself at the moment, but there are some cases where you have to invoke `cmake` twice, sometimes with different arguments. Generally the first time will generate a bunch of build-related files, and the second time will actually perform the build. If there's a README with that project, it should explain what commands to run, if this is possible. You may also need to be running inside a Visual Studio Command Prompt, for some of the actual build.

Comment: Look at this: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html
they even say thats the way...

Comment: When I hit "configure" CMake generates lots of files, and when I hit "build" it makes the VS2010 solution and projects

Comment: thats totally ok. after that, you click the opencv.sln file, and compile all the projects generated. last step is: run the INSTALL project to copy the libs / headers/dlls to your final destination

Comment: Thanks berak, I already had done it :) I just thought CMake could do it all at once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [CMake page](http://www.cmake.org/):

"CMake is used to control the software compilation process using simple platform and compiler independent configuration files. ***CMake generates native makefiles and workspaces that can be used in the compiler environment of your choice***."

On the OpenCV website you can find a [complete guide](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) to the installation on your Windows machine

Comment: Yes, that's the tutorial I was looking, but cant CMake also just call the compiler and build it, saving me one more step?

Comment: No it can't... if you want to automatize the process you should look at the MSBuild tool

Comment: So, what's the real bennefit of using it? Just to download some code and have it all added in an IDE of your choice, saving you the time of configuring it?

Comment: This is the main reason... and a very important one!